# How to extract Joomla image PHP for Opengraph

Tags: php, templates, template-override, external-script

I have been trying to develop my own opengraph. I found some codes online and try to merge them but to no avail. I wonder if I have done it wrong.

```
// Try to find image in article
         $img = 0;
         $fulltext = '';
         if (isset($row->fulltext) && $row->fulltext != '') {
        $fulltext = $row->fulltext;
         }
         $introtext = '';
         if (isset($row->introtext) && $row->introtext != '') {
            $fulltext = $row->introtext;
         }
         $content = $introtext . $fulltext;
         preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $content, $src);
         if (isset($src[1]) && $src[1] != '') {
            $timage = htmlspecialchars($src[1]));
            $img = 1;
         }

$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '
<meta property="og:title" content="'.$this->escape($this->item->title).'"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="'.$timage.'";/>
');
```

Second Code I am experimenting (I received the Undefined Variable : timage

```
function get_joomla_image($url)
    {
            if (preg_match('/< *img[^>]*src *= *["\']?([^"\']*)/i', $url, $match)) {
            $timage = $match[1];
            echo $match[1];
        }
    }



// get the corresponding thumbnail images   
if (isset($match[1]) and !empty($match[1]))
{
 $timage= htmlspecialchars(JURI::root().$match[1]);
}

$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '
<meta name="og:image" content="'.$timage.'">
```

Thank you Joomla guru for your help.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($match);` to see what the variable contains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of `preg_match`? That way you should be able to get all images in the body using `getElementsByTagName()`. Maybe something like this could work:

```
$buffer = JResponse::getBody();
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($buffer);

$images = $document->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

`$images` will be an object containing all elements (images) in your document. If you want to get the URL of the first image, you can use

```
 $image = $images->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

then

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addCustomTag( '
   <meta name="og:image" content="'.$image.'">
');
```

Just some quick ideas, you'll probably have to modify the code to make it work.

Comment: When using your code, I received this error message when loading locally. `Notice: Undefined variable: images in C:\xampp\htdocs\tyoga\templates\tyoga\html\com_content\article\default.php on line 13` `Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\tyoga\templates\tyoga\html\com_content\article\default.php on line 13` I hope dont mind giving me some enlightenment

Comment: For researchers: `JResponse::getBody()` is deprecated since **Joomla 3.2** and should be replaced with `JFactory::getApplication()->getBody()`  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/10233/12352

Answer (score 2):

> *For your Error:- Undefined Variable : timage*

I have noticed that **$timage** variable is declared inside **condition statement** in both code.

```
 if (isset($src[1]) && $src[1] != '') {
            $timage = htmlspecialchars($src[1]));
            $img = 1;
         }
```

If above condition fails, **$timage** variable will never be declared. Try declaring this variable outside statement and change value as per condition.   Hope this helps.